# Threads of one process in parallel execution

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I know, that threads exist in borders of process: each process has at least 1 thread and thread can't exist without process; threads share memory and processes does not(without special manipulations) and so on. Also we can load CPU cores by giving it multiple processes to execute at the same time. 
But can we execute multiple threads of the SAME process at one time(i mean real parallel execution, not pseudo-parallel) and if we can, is it better than using mupltiple processes and why?
Thank you for answer!

Comment: If your machine has multiple cores why not. It is better, because threads have a lower overhead compared to processes.

Answer (score 0):

Threads are basically lightweight processes. OS threads can be executed in parallel, real parallel execution requires just having multiple CPU cores.

The threads have lower isolation since they share memory and can clobber each other's memory, unlike processes. The upside is that they generally have less metadata associated with them and are easier/faster to create, so you can have more of them running at the same time, than processes.

Comment: But are there any tasks in which multiprocessing is better than multithreading? (The only task i know is python's GIL bypass using multiple processes)

Comment: @violetapple, Here's one reason you might choose to create a new process instead of a new thread: You can design a system in which some un-trustworthy or un-reliable process can be safely killed. It is nearly impossible to build a system in which it is safe to allow other threads to run after one thread has been killed.

Comment: @SolomonSlow thank you, i didn't know that.
Now i can fall asleep :D

Comment: Oops! I meant to say, "...safe to allow other threads _in the same process_ to run after one thread _in that process_ has been killed."